# _.each function for looping in JS issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

We are asked to do the following:

Write a function called checkValue that searches an array for a value. It takes an array and a value and returns true if the value exists in the array, otherwise it returns false.

```
var helloArr = ['bonjour', 'hello', 'hola'];

var checkValue = function(arr, val) {
//checks if the val is in arr
}
```

Rewrite checkValue using _.each.

here is what I have to itterate over helloArr using _.each:

```
var helloArr = ['bonjour', 'hello', 'hola'];

var checkValue = function (num) {
return num;
}
checkValue('hola');

var output = us.each(helloArr, function(num){
if (checkValue())
    {return true;}});

return output;
```

What am I doing wrong? When I run it with node, theres no errors but no output either. I know you can use _.find to do this but the spec is asking to itterate over the array and find the value using _.each.

Comment: is indexOf('hola') > 0 not good enough?

Comment: What is the point of checkValue?

Comment: checkValue is supposed to check is supposed to check if a specific value is in the array. Without _.each, its pretty easy:

    var helloArr = ['bonjour', 'hello', 'hola'];

    var checkValue = function(arr, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
 if (val == arr[i]){ console.log(true);}else{
  console.log(false);
 }
    }
    }
    checkValue(helloArr,'hola');
The problem arrises when the spec says to do the same with _.each.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" There are a lot of problems with the code listed in the question. But at a higher level, you should learn the basics of the language and the underscore library and rewrite the solution from scratch rather than trying to identify and fix an isolated issue in this draft.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, you're calling `checkValue` without a parameter, so it's going to return `undefined`, which is a falsey value, and the callback to `each` never returns anything.

Then again, it doesn't normally need to return anything *anyway*. `_.each` returns the list it operates on.

`_.each` is like a for-loop; consider treating it more like one.

```
function checkValue_original1(arr, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (val == arr[i]) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function checkValue_original2(arr, val) {
    return arr.indexOf(val) >= 0;
}

function checkValue_us_each(arr, val) {
    var found = false;
    _.each(arr, function(element, index, list) {
        if (element == val) found = true;
    });
    return found;
}
```